# For array in sql

Tags: php, mysql

```
$this->db->select('id');$this->db->from('tasks');
$this->db->where('task_type','MS');
$subQuery = $this->db->get();
$result = $subQuery->result();
$this->db->from($this->tasks.' as t');
$this->db->join($this->projects.' as p', 'p.id = t.project_id','left');
$this->db->select('t.*,p.project_name');
```

I want to check the `$result` array values in following WHERE clause for `ms_id` value exist in `$result` or not.

Out For eg.

```
$this->db->where(array('t.company_id'=>$company_id,'t.user_id'=>$user_id,'t.active'=>1,'p.is_template'=>0,'p.project_status'=>'active','t.task_type'=>'TD'));
```

Answer (score 0):

check your model. you should code like this one :

```
//QUERY ON MODEL
public function function_name($id){
$this->db->select('table_contain_name.id, table_contain_name.name, table_contain_name.address, table_contain_name.id_religion, table_religion.religion_name')
         ->from('table_contain_name')
         ->join('table_religion', 'table_religion.id=table_contain_name.id_religion)
         ->where('table_contain_name.id', $id)
         ->where('table_religion.religion_name', 'name of religion');
$data = $this->db->get();
return $data->result();
}
```

it will work for you..